# How to reduce the size of logo in print order? Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I have added below code in sales_order_print.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo"  remove="true" />
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="print_logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">147</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">24</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <move element="print_logo" destination="page.main.title" before="-"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="main"/>
</body>
```

But the logo can be very large, I want to reduce the height of logo so it can be show proper in print, I already give height size 24 but no luck, please help how can I do that?

Comment: From frontend or backend?

Comment: Frontend @sumit

Comment: Are you using any third party extension for this?

Comment: no i am not using any third party extension

Comment: Problem is solved @Sumit

Comment: Can you please share your solution here. As I've checked for it and did not find anything related to the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98899/discussion-between-magento-and-sumit).